# mediatomb autostart doesn't work

Tags: networking, autostart, mediatomb

mediatomb works fine when starting manually but the autostart doesn't work.
In the wiki it says it should start automatically at system start, but it doesn't. 
tryed many things but still doesn't work any ideas??

Comment: When I figure this out, I will answer your question. It might take a week or more before I get some time to sit down with it.  I'm having the same issue on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience, you should first configure it to your liking using your own account and testing it manually from the command line.

When you have everything set up, you should copy your `~/.mediatomb/config.xml` file to the global localtion (which is read by the mediatomb service during startup) `/etc/mediatomb/config.xml`.

I'm not sure, but you might have to fix permissions so mediatomb can read (write?) from your home folder or wherever your media files are.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. My mediatomb works fine when I run it from my logged-in session. But, when I restart my server, even though mediatomb is a service within /etc/init.d/rc3.d , the server fails to start.